# Anything I can possibly to do recover data from factory reset iPhone 6, without using iCloud or iTunes

Tags: data-recovery, iphone

anyone know how to recover data from an iPhone 6 after it has been disabled due to too many passcode lock attempts and then having to factory reset it. I backed up my phone from my iCloud account, but that was only backed up till October. I have some super important data and sentimental pix/vid.

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 

Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

The contents of an iDevice are hardware encrypted. Resetting clears the encryption keys, making recovery impossible.